# Android - Keeping screen brightness through entire application

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, screen-brightness

I currently have a button in my application that changes the screen brightness, but when I leave that activity, it resets the screen brightness back to normal. I want it to set the brightness throughout the entire application, but go back to normal when I close the application.

This is the code I have now:

```
public void lower(View view) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    float brightness = (float) 0.01;
    lp.screenBrightness = brightness;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  
}

public void raise(View view) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    float brightness = (float) -1;
    lp.screenBrightness = brightness;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
}
```

I was thinking I might be able to do a sort of `getScreenBrightness` type method on the `onCreate()` method of my other activities, but this doesn't work.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you will need to create separate class for accessing these two methods for all activites

Comment: Ok. What do I need to add into this class?

Comment: nothing more just move these methods in separate class and pass Activity context to it for setting Brightness when u call these methods for activities